# GoogleCloudMessaging register() gives SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error after uninstall and reinstall the Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to get registrationID from GCM, it works fine for the first time I install the app, then I store it in sharedPreference.
However, after uninstalling and installing app again, I keep getting SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error when the following codes run.
The code to get registrationID:

```
 GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    regId = gcm.register(Constants.PROJECT_NUMBER.toString())
```

;

I got IOException:
SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Any ideas about it?

Comment: The SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE could occur when truly the GCM server is not available and hence you could try after sometime. Can you paste your code to see if there is something else missing ?

Comment: Hi, Sachin , thanks for your reply. I used the following code proposed by google, please check the link : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid    . The code reached in the following block: } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }. error is: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: Thanks Brian for updating question format.